# How to throw parameters from the frontend to the backend

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Put the List data into the label1 and click button

I want to pass the label1 parameters(9) from the foreground to the background

but can't get right parameters(9) from the background label1
.aspx

```
<html>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="getPage('9')">23123</a></li>
</ul>
</html>

<asp:Button ID="selected_items" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick ="selected_items_Click"  />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>


<script>

    function getPage(deldata) {
        console.log(deldata);
    
        $(LId).val(deldata);
        $(LId).text(deldata);
 
    
        $(btnId).click();
    }

</script>
```

.cs

```
     protected void selected_items_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           
            string a = Label1.Text;
            string data= Request.Form["Label1"];
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my code and implement in your project.

```
<html>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getPage('9')">23123</a></li>
</ul>
</html>

<asp:Button ID="selected_items" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="selected_items_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

<script>

    function getPage(deldata) {
        console.log(deldata);

        $("#Label1").text(deldata);


        $("#selected_items").click();
    }

</script>

protected void selected_items_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           
            string a = Label1.Text;
            string data= Request.Form["Label1"];
       }
```

Comment: You mean like this "getPage('')"?